# Get an error when calling the @Test annotation - new to Java - just started

Tags: java

I just started learning Java and got the below error when calling the @Test annotation.

> Syntax error on token "void", interface expected

Can someone help me please? Thanks!

```
package personTestpackage;

import org.junit.Test;

public void PersonTest {        

    @Test
            public void shouldReturnHelloWorld() {
            Person  irandi = new Person ();
            assertEquals("Hello World", irandi.helloWorld() );

        }

    private void assertEquals(String string, String helloWorld) {

    }

    }
```

Comment: You have `public void PersonTest {`. I believe you meant `public class PersonTest {`. Also, JUnit should provide you with an `assertEquals` method; no need to write your  own.

Answer (score 0):

The fixed code will look like this:

```
package personTestpackage;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class PersonTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnHelloWorld() {
        Person irandi = new Person();
        Assert.assertEquals("Hello World", irandi.helloWorld());
    }
}

class Person {
    public String helloWorld() {
            return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Notes:

- Your compilation error is because `PersonTest` should be a  `class`, not a `void` method.
- JUnit already provides you with `Assert#assertEquals` methods, note that `Assert` class is imported with `import org.junit.Assert`.
- I've added a mock `Person` class just to make the code compile and execute.